# How can i get Default mail address and phone number from iOS Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidevice

As of i know we can get only these but i need to get Email and phone , is there any idea or anyone implemented befor?

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *name;              // e.g. "My iPhone"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *model;             // e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *localizedModel;    // localized version of model
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *systemName;        // e.g. @"iOS"
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) NSString    *systemVersion;     // e.g. @"4.0"
NSString *dnamee= [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
```

Comment: Unless the device is jailbroken, you can't.

Comment: my device is jail Broken only , Can you tell how can i get ?